# Making sure a number is part of a set (javascript)

Tags: javascript, numbers, set

So lets say I have a set of numbers 1 through 6. I want to check that a variable is part of this set.

How do in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: `if (1 >= x && x <= 6)`?

Comment: What do you mean by set? How is the set stored in memory?

Comment: @BradChristie Nice one! :)) My guess is that it's all about `Array.indexOf()`.

Comment: Theres no restriction. I found the Set class but wasn't sure how to use it. Rashmirathi's answer is what I was after. Thanks everyone.

Comment: google "javascript set"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
s.has(1); // returns true
s.has(100); // returns false
```

Comment: Ahh I did find the set class. Thanks for showing how to use it.

Comment: Yeh this works perfectly thanks. I was doing navigation to divs and wanted to make sure it was always to the correctly numbered ones.